# Button to change color of <td>

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am trying to make an interactive periodic table of elements. I need to change the background color of more `<td>` with the `classname "nemetale"` when a button is clicked. It's not working, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

There is the button

```
 <button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('.nemetale').style.backgroundColor = 'red';">Nemetale</button>
```

There is one of the `<td>s`.

```
<table class="tabel_periodic">
  <!--Randul 1-->
  <tr>

   <td class="nemetale">
    <strong>1</strong><br>
    <acronym>H</acronym><br>
    <em>Hidrogen</em><br>
    <i>1,008</i>
   </td>
 ...
```

Comment: The method is called `getElementsByClassName`, with a capital "N" for "Name"

Comment: It's not working

Comment: This is both off-topic due to a typo and a duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845/4642212). Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: @CristianMaranca also consider that `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object, so you have to iterate the result, not simply set its `style`.

Comment: Use the console and the typo would be quickly revealed (F12 in Chrome):
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassmame is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test2.htm:2)

Comment: @CristianMaranca - thanks for marking my answer as correct. Could you also please up-vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

Firstly, there is a typo in the function you call. It should be `getElementsByClassName()`.

Secondly, [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) returns a NodeList. This is “like” an Array, but it means you have to select each item from the NodeList.

If there is only one element, you can do

`document.getElementsByClassName('nemetale')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';`

If there is more than one element you will have to loop through the items. I recommend making it a function.

```
<button onclick="highlight">Nemetale</button>

function highlight() {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('nemetale');

    Array.from(items).forEach(function(item) {
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    });
}
```

If you are using ES6, you can make it a bit shorter as well:

```
function highlight() {
    const items = document.getElementsByClassName('nemetale');

    Array.from(items).forEach(item => item.style.backgroundColor = 'red');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/439/)**.

> **getElementsByClassName() :** Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

The function `.getElementsByClassmame()` doesn't exist you should use **[`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**.

Since the `.getElementsByClassName()` return a list of elements you should return the first element instead using `[0]` like :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('nemetale')[0].style.backgroundColor  = 'red';
```

```js
var trs = document.getElementsByClassName('nemetale');

document.getElementById('change_color').addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
    changeColor(trs[i]);
  }
});

function changeColor(tr) {
  tr.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

```html
<button id="change_color">Nemetale</button>

<table class="tabel_periodic">
  <tr>
    <td class="nemetale">
      <strong>1</strong><br>
      <acronym>H</acronym><br>
      <em>Hidrogen</em><br>
      <i>1,008</i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nemetale">
      <strong>2</strong><br>
      <acronym>H</acronym><br>
      <em>Hidrogen</em><br>
      <i>2,008</i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nemetale">
      <strong>3</strong><br>
      <acronym>H</acronym><br>
      <em>Hidrogen</em><br>
      <i>3,008</i>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: <button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('nemetale')[0]style.backgroundColor = 'red';">Nemetale</button>

Comment: I used it like that, it works, it changes the color of the first element, but i want to change the color of all the elements in this class.

Comment: @CristianMaranca - You will have to loop through the collection. You can see how to do this in my answer.

Comment: @CristianMaranca `[0]style‌` is invalid syntax. You mean `[0].style‌`.

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo: **getElementsByClassmame**, this isn't a valid JS method.

Use .querySelector instead:

```
document.querySelector('.nemetale')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d5dg0uw4/

Answer (score -2):

Make it like below by adding function:

```
<button onclick="changeBackgroundColor()">Nemetale</button>
```

put this into

```
<script>
  function changeBackgroundColor(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('nemetale')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Then close the question, don't downvote correct answers.